# T-SQL CTE char() function not the same type as cast( as char)

Tags: sql, t-sql, char

I wanted to create a small cte for the chars [a-z].
However if I use the char()-function for the recursive part like this:

```
with cte(chars)
as (
    select cast('a' as char) as chars
    union all
    select char(ascii(chars) + 1 ) from cte
    where chars < 'z'
)
select *
from cte
```

the data-types don't match even tho char() returns a char(1).
But if the char()-function is casted to char(1), it runs perfectly fine:

```
with cte(chars)
as (
    select cast('a' as char) as chars
    union all
    select cast(char(ascii(chars) + 1 ) as char) from cte
    where chars < 'z'
)
select *
from cte
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, *never* use `char()` (and related types) without a length.  The default length varies by context -- and who wants to keep track of such things?

The following works:

```
with cte(chars) as (
      select cast('a' as char(1)) as chars
      union all
      select char(ascii(chars) + 1 ) from cte
      where chars < 'z'
     )
select *
from cte;
```

In other words, the default length for a `char()` in a `cast()` is different from the default length in a `declare`.

Comment: the hovertext of the cast-function showed me 'retruns char(1)'. that's why i was suprised about the error. nevertheless your answer makes totaly sense to me. thx